# So I can't dynamic_cast< functionPointer >( ((void*)(myFuncPtr)) )? What should I do?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, dynamic-cast

I have a base class, Parameter, and two derived classes: Scalar & Vector.  In each derived class, I have a member function which takes a function pointer as input:

In the Scalar class:

```
typedef double (*samplerType)(RandNum& rnState);
void RegisterSampler( samplerType input );
```

In the Vector class:

```
typedef std::vector<double> (*samplerType)(RandNum& rnState);
void RegisterSampler( samplerType input );
```

Note the different return types: `double` and `std::vector<double>`.  I would like to define this function within the mutual base class, Parameter -- so I changed the functions to take `(void* input)` and then tried the following when defining the functions within the Scalar & Vector classes:

samplerType inputSampler = dynamic_cast< samplerType >(input);

However, I get the following error in VS 2005:

```
error C2680: 'double (__cdecl *)(RandNum &)' : invalid target type for dynamic_cast
target type must be a pointer or reference to a defined class
```

Grumble Grumble Grumble...  I'm not sure if this is valid (standard permitting) C++ or not, but I guess either way I'll treat this as a flaw in my design.

**So**, My standard approach would be to template the base class with the return type of the function, but I can't.  The base class, Parameter, must -- by design -- be free of all type information.  **Is there a different way to design the inheritance?**

My attempts to Google this have turned up virtually nil on function pointers -- Hence I'll believe that this is in fact *invalid syntax*, but perhaps just a *really, really* uncommon design challenge? **Is this another one of those places, *functors* to the rescue?**

Comment: I don't understand the rationale: why do you want this typeless `Parameter` member to be in the base class? You can't use it since its type is unknown. A function object can't help you (unless you did something ugly like declare it as returning a `boost::any`) because the return type is essential to the type of the function object.

Comment: I don't want it in the Base class, but I want access to the Registration function from a base class pointer.  In other words, I have an array of Parameter* and I'd like to register a function which I know has the correct signature for given Parameter*.

Comment: To what end?  You can't use it unless you know its actual type, which from what you have said is dependent upon the derived classes, right?

Comment: It doesn't seem like very good form to have a registration function in the base class that takes functions (pointers or objects) that actually return different types, as this difference is depended upon by the descendant classes and thus breaks polymorphism.

Comment: Yes, I have a Parameter*, but I happen to know its true derived type. I'd like to call RegisterSampler on the Parameter*, but I guess I should just dynamic_cast< DerivedType* > first to avoid this whole mishegoss.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the design flaw that James points out, it's true that you can't cast from a function pointer to a normal `void*` pointer. You can however cast between function pointers of arbitary types (free-to-free, member-to-member):

```
typedef void (*samplerType)();
// in base class ...
samplerType sampler_;
template<class F>
void RegisterSampler(F sampler){
  // template so the user doesn't have to do the type cast
  sampler_ = reinterpret_cast<samplerType>(sampler);
}
// in derived class, where you access the sampler, you need to cast it back:
// (scalar)
typedef double (*realSamplerType)(RandNum& rnState);
// made-up function ...
void UseSampler(){
  realSamplerType sampler = reinterpret_cast<realSamplerType>(sampler_);
  double ret = sampler(param...);
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and got:

`error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'Matrix<> (__cdecl *)(RandNum &)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(RandNum &)'
Incompatible calling conventions for UDT return value`

Comment: @M. Tibbits: Lemme check that.

Comment: What you're saying looks reasonable, I just found [this link](http://learningcppisfun.blogspot.com/2005/07/casting-cv-qualifier-and-function.html), interesting read which agrees with you -- though you lose type-safety...  type-safety? what type-safety?

Comment: @M. Tibbits: My bad, you of course need a `reinterpret_cast` there. I have a bad habbit of just using C-Style casts so I always forget when to use which C++ cast...

Comment: Well done.  Just thought I'd add that a simple C-cast `((void(*)(RandNum& rnState))(myFunc))` also works.

Comment: @M. Tibbits: You can even use the `typedef`d version. :) That's what I meant with C-Style cast in my earlier comment. And the "void" function pointer doesn't need a parameter btw. Aside from that, `dynamic_cast` is only for pointers to struct/class objects, from base to derived and such.